# Inscribed circles inside an equilateral triangle

Tags: measure-theory

Circles of identical size are inscribed inside equilateral triangle (Figure 1). Find the limit of the ratio of the area covered by the circles and the area of the triangle as the number of circles tends to infinity.

[image: circles inscribed in the triangle]

***Solution given by the author***:

The limit in question equals the proportion of the area of triangle connecting the centers of three inner circles covered by those three circles, which is
$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$

I don't understand how did the author compute this answer? What is the logic author applied here?

Would any member explain this answer?

Comment: How does your title connected with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Heron's formula,
$a=b=c$, $s=\frac{3a}{2}$

Area of triangle in red part:
$$\text{Area of triangle} = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}= \frac{a^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}$$
As $a=3d=6r$, $$\text{Area of triangle} = \frac{36r^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}= 9r^2 \sqrt{3}$$

Area of circle inside red part:
$$\text{Area of circle} = \frac{9\pi r^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{\text{Area of circle}}{\text{Area of triangle}}=\frac{\frac{9\pi r^2}{2}}{9r^2 \sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}$$

So the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$.

---

**Aother way to see:**

When $n\to\infty$, the side of triangle is closer to n times the radius $r$.

Suppose $a=b=c=nd=2nr$.

From Heron's formula again,
$$\text{Area of triangle} = \frac{4n^2 r^2 \sqrt{3}}{4}= n^2 r^2 \sqrt{3}$$

Number of circle = $1+2+\cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$$\text{Area of circle} = \frac{n(n+1)\pi r^2}{2}$$

$$\frac{\text{Area of circle}}{\text{Area of triangle}}=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)\pi r^2}{2}}{n^2 r^2 \sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}\cdot (1+\frac{1}{n}) \to \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: For this answer, I make some typos about d and r , so there is some mistakes, please tell me if there is any typos.

Comment: I accept your second answer titled "Another way to see". Because I also computed in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your picture, where I've coloured part of the triangle in red, and the rest in blue:

[image: Figure 1 with colours.]

Two remarks:

- Inside the red part, no matter how many circles there are, the proportion of the area covered by circles is always equal to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$;
- The total area of the blue part converges to $0$ as the number of circles tends to infinity.

Taken together, these two things imply that the proportion of the area of the whole triangle that is covered by circles converges to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$ as the number of circles tends to infinity.