# Proportion of area covered by circles

Tags: geometry, limits, circles

For the two **attached** images herewith, let $P_n$ denote the proportion of the big circle covered by the small circles  as function of the number of the small circles in the outer layer. Find the expression for $P_n$ and compute the $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$$[image]

**Author's answer to this question as follows:** Let R be the radius of the big circle, $r_n$ be the radius of the small circles in the outer layer, and $R_n$ be the radius of the circle encompassing all small circles except those in the outer layer. Then in both cases $P_n R^2\pi = n r^2_n \pi + P_n R^2_n \pi (\star)$ and $\sin{\frac{\pi}{n} }= \frac{r_n}{R - r_n}$ In the first case, $R_n= R- 2r_n$, giving $$ P_n = \frac{nr_n}{4(R-r_n)} = \frac{n \sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{4}, \lim_{n \to \infty} =\frac{\pi}{4}$$

In the second case  we have $(R-r_n) \cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}- \sqrt{(r_n + \hat{r}_n )^2 - r^2_n} + \hat{r}_n = R_n $ where $\hat{r}_n $ is the radius of the circle in the second outer layer $\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}} = \frac{\hat{r}_n}{R_n -\hat{r}_n}$. The last two relations yield $R_2$ to be substituted in $(\star)$ whence we get an expression for $P_n$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

I agree with the author's answer in the first case. But in the second case, I got $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n =\displaystyle\frac{n \cdot r_n}{2R - r_n}$$ Now, how is this expression for $P_n$ equal to $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$
Is this final answer computed similar to that computed in this question titled [Inscribed circles inside an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4735973/153118)

If any member of Mathematics  stack exchange knows satisfactory answers to my questions, may anwer them.

Comment: What has this to do with probability, measure theory or stochastic analysis????

Comment: I think the following link will answer your question.https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318225973_Exercises_in_Stochastic_Calculus

Comment: Yes, as is often the case with a list of problems of increasing difficulty on a topic, the first, or the first few problems, may not be closely related to the topic. It's a way to make you use what you already know.

Comment: Regarding your questions, everything is relatively obvious: the two cases are the two ways to fill the large circle with smaller ones (circle centers from all layers aligned in the first case, or packed in the second). Since $n$ is the number of circles on the outer layer, $\pi/n$ is the angle $O$ in the triangle $OPT$, where $O$ is the center of the large circle, $P$ the center of one of the small outer circles, and $T$ the contact with the tangent to this circle that passes through $O$. Obviously the angle $T$ is right.

Comment: As to the formula $\sin(\pi/r_n)=\frac{r_n}{R-r_n}$, it's just a basic trigonometric relation in the triangle $OPT$, use the definition of sine. All of this is pretty basic geometry. To find the next layer (first case), adjust $R$ to consider a new "large circle", that spans up to the second layer and leaves the first. Hence $R'=R-2r_n$. For the second case you need some more work based on Pythagoras theorem and basic trigonometry.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore I suggest that you post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I think the $\triangle OPT$ is an isosceles triangle. $\therefore$ How can we say $m\angle OPT =90^\circ ? $ The angle at the center O is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ So, other two angles of this isosceles triangle must be equal.

Comment: The angle $T$ is right. The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of contact. The angle $O$ in the triangle $OPT$ is $\pi/n$, not $2\pi/n$.

Comment: Answer to this question has been  already provided by the author. I just try to understand some of its parts which are unclear to me.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, We get, in the second case $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n= \displaystyle\frac{n \cdot r_n}{2R - r_n}$$ How can we say it is equal to $$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}?$$